# sql developer debugger ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out

Tags: debugging, oracle-sqldeveloper

I work with SQL Developer and I want to debug a package procedure.

I run the debug some times and these are the different values of host and port

```
 CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '10.50.10.117', '62378' )
 CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '10.50.10.117', '62388' )
```

These are the sql developer preferences

[image]

I added the line

```
AddVMOption -DDatabaseDebuggerDisableJDWP=true
```

in the file sqldeveloper.conf

I have a question: is it mandatory to open the port 4000?

The error is

```
Connecting to the database Copernico Produccion 1.
Executing PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '10.50.10.117', '62378' )
ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger
ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out
```

I am able to connect to database

Comment: If the AddVMOption -DDatabaseDebuggerDisableJDWP=true flag was being honored correctly, you wouldn't be seeing ANY calls to DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP

Comment: the db is trying to talk to port 62378 on your machine, assuming you have sqldev running on 10.50.10.117

Comment: My port changes everytime I executed the debug. How do I have to open this port for the debug?

Comment: open a port range and in the preferences define the range of ports to use, that range could be just 1 port